# Resigning from my postion, with two weeks notice, one week is planned vacation

Tags: employer

I am leaving my job of 2 1/2 years, because I new job has been offered to me. I have had a week vacation planned for over 5 months. That vacation week will fall on the 2nd week of my two weeks notice. Can they refuse to accept that vacation time as part of my two weeks?

Comment: Likely depends on where you're working. Also, I'm assuming you already have this vacation approved and you're wondering if they can withdraw their approval if you hand in your notice, right?

Comment: I think you can since your vacation was already planned, you should check this with your company. You're not giving your boss a lot of time to find a new employee - but two weeks notice is two weeks notice.

Comment: Thanks I agree, I know its short notice for the boss, but I am done with that place. It is a private school and some of the policies I can no longer deal with. That is also the same week vacation I took last year and already have in for 2017.

Comment: This could be country-dependant, would you please add this information?

Comment: This is highly country dependent but in most jurisdiction with regulated paid annual vacation employee can cancel vacation only on special, unexpected circumstances. I believe he could however argue that they need you for knowledge transfer or business continuity but from my experience It never happens.

Comment: In the US, yes of course they can withdraw the leave.  It is very likely they will (if they need you to spend the time in turnover of your duties)  or they will terminate you early. From their perspective, why should they give you a benefit that is no longer in their best interest?

Comment: I am in the United States.

Comment: I dont think they would need me to train anyone, I teach and there are other staff in the school that were already covering my vacation and have been in my room and work with me, so I assume they would just continue where I left off. My concern is they will not pay me for my vacation time earned. It has been scheduled for months now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read your employee handbook, as this is specifc to a companies policies and most likely will be spelled out clearly.

At my company for example, it specifically states if you want any PTO to be paid out as part of your final check you cannot use vacation as part of your two weeks notice period.

You may want to consider working 1 week, do your vacation, then work another week to fullfill the 2 weeks notice.

Comment: I have never worked for a company that would allow anyone to take leave during their notice period, pre-planned or not.  The rules on this are almost always spelled out in the employee handbook as you pointed out.

Answer (score -2):

I have two friends who decided to leave as well from my company. They had three weeks of notice. They actually resigned on Monday and left last friday. And for the two remaining weeks it was planned holidays. In that case it worked.

To be sure I would get in touch with the Human resources. Of course you might be able to do it, but be sure you don't leave a bittersweet image of yourself once leaving the company not to put them in an uncomfortable situation regarding the way you left.

In my case my two colleagues spent their last week training the person that would be replacing them in the company in the meantime they recruit someone else...